# Get stats of number of files of unqiue file extensions including binaries from command line

Tags: command-line, find

I am trying to recursively count the number of different extensions and how often each of them occurs in the files of a directory and I want to include the number of files with no extension. I am trying:

```
find . -type f -name "*.*" | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | 
  grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{2,16}" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | 
   sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

But this does not display binaries with no extensions. How can I do this correctly?

UPDATE : My main intention is top find out how many files and its total size of terraform / terraform plugin binaries are downloaded in one particular folder so that I can view them and delete them.

Comment: Remove the `-name "*.*"` part?

Comment: Its still not showing. I had it as `*` alone.

Comment: It shows a list of files here, and includes all files.
`find . -type f  | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" | grep -o -E "[[:alpha:]]{2,16}" | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn`

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to *explain what outcome you want*? `grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$"` is also going to exclude results that don't have "dot extensions" (btw you don't need to escape `.` inside `[]`). If you are using that as a kind of `basename` function there are simpler alternatives

Comment: "Perhaps it would be helpful to explain what outcome you want?" - I have an `uploads` folder which is 800GB - I want to know whats in there. Need to offload binaries which are mainly terraform binaries.

Comment: So... what does that mean *programatically*? Do you want to find files with a particular name pattern? a particular size range? a particular mime type? I'm trying to understand how your pipeline is intended to implement your goal

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) explain what you are trying to do and ii) show us a few example file names and the output you expect from that example. Make sure to include both things that should be found and things that should not be found.

Answer (score 3):

The `-name "*.*"` in your `find` already excludes any file with no extension since you are looking only for files with at least one `.` and then, your `grep` is explicitly removing files without extensions:

```
grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$"
```

This will print the extension, but if the file has no extension it will print nothing:

```
$ echo 'foo.txt' | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" 
.txt
$ echo 'foo' | grep -o -E "\.[^\.]+$" 
$
```

If what you want is to count the number of occurrences for each extension or no extension, try this instead:

```
find . -type f | 
    awk -F'.' '{
                 if(NF>2){ 
                    ext=tolower($NF)
                    k["."ext]++ } 
                 else{ k["no extension"]++ } 
               }
               END{ for(i in k){ print i":"k[i] } }'
```

For example, given this directory:

```
$ touch file{1..3}.txt file.jpg file.JPG file."weird extension with spaces" file
$ ls
 file   file1.txt   file2.txt   file3.txt   file.jpg  file.JPG 
 'file.weird extension with spaces'
```

You get:

```
$ find . -type f | 
>     awk -F'.' '{
>                  if(NF>2){ 
>                     ext=tolower($NF)
>                     k["."ext]++ } 
>                  else{ k["no extension"]++ } 
>                }
>                END{ for(i in k){ print i":"k[i] } }'
no extension:1
.txt:3
.weird extension with spaces:1
.jpg:2
```

Note that this will consider a hidden file, for example something named `.hidden`, as its own extension. That would be counted as one hit for the extension `.hidden`. Hidden files with extensions will be counted correctly (i.e. `.hidden.txt` will increase the hits for the `.txt` extension), but those without extension will not. I don't know how you want to handle that since extensions are largely cosmetic in Linux.

By the way, whether a file is binary or not has nothing to do with whether it has an extension or not.

Comment: +1 was about to post essentially the same except with GNU awk to roll in the sort-by-count `gawk -F. '{c[tolower(NF > 1 ? $NF : "none")]++} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"; for(i in c) print c[i], i}'`

Comment: Heh, great minds and all that, @steeldriver! I think it's still worth posting yours though precisely because of the nice gawk trick. But I will add the tolower, I forgot that from the OP.

Comment: ... or fools ;) I'm happy for you to include it as a variant, tbh I'm still waiting for the OP to clarify exactly how this helps solve "Need to offload binaries which are mainly terraform binaries."

Comment: +1 ... But, does it need to be that complicated :) ... Whats wrong with e.g. `awk -F'.' '{ext[tolower($3)]++} END {for (t in ext) print t, ext[t]}'` ?

Comment: @Raffa first, that won't print the number of files with no extension. If you have a file named `foo`, it will simply not be counted and that's one of the main requirements of the OP. Second, if you have a file named `foo.bar.baz.txt`, yours will take `bar` as the extension and not `.txt`. That's why I'm using `$NF` and not `$3` in mine. Finally, I also wanted to include the `.` in the extension for clarity, hence the `k["."ext]++` as opposed to `ext[tolower($NF)]++`.

Comment: It does count files with no extension but, the number only is printed(*e.g. 10*) ... The other `$NF` idea however might be indeed worth the little extra complexity :-)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right, @raffa. But exactly, since only a space and a number were printed, I didn't even notice it!